# Remove all the validations on a FormControl

Tags: angular, formbuilder, form-control, angular2-validators

How Can I remove all the validations on a FormControl ( which is a component in this case ).

I declared the FormControl like this in the constructor :

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
  fileUploadControl: new FormControl()
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [clearValidators()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#clearValidators)

```
this.form.get('fileUploadControl').clearValidators();
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I was looking for :)